# Proper form validation with Spring MVC 3 - catching PersistenceException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been looking for a way to make form validation as easy and unobtrusive as possible in Spring MVC 3. I like the way spring can handle Bean Validation by passing @Valid to my model (that has been annotated with validator annotations) and using the result.hasErrors() method.

I am setting up my controller actions like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/domainofexpertise", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String addDomainOfExpertise(@ModelAttribute("domainOfExpertise") 
@Valid DomainOfExpertise domainOfExpertise, final BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "/domainofexpertise/add";
    } else {
        domainOfExpertiseService.save(domainOfExpertise);
        return "redirect:/admin/domainofexpertise/list";
    }
}
```

Which works like a charm. Database exceptions (like trying to save something with a unique constraint on a field) will still get through. Is there any way to incorporate catching those exceptions in the validation process going on behind the scenes? This way of validating is very concise so I want to avoid having to manually catch them in my controller.

Any information on this?

Comment: The validation at the controller is to prevent the call propagation till the database layer, but why would you want the Database exceptions to be handled at this layer. If you get an exception at the DB layer you should propagate till controller and either show the errors or redirect to a different page. If you are doing here i am seeing a breach of seperation of concerns. Just my thoughts.

Comment: So I should catch the persistence exceptions in the save method of my service layer? What would be a proper way of returning the exceptions to the controller when doing this?

Comment: There are several ways you can interpret your exceptions, one among them is as below mentioned by Luciano to a have a generic ExceptionHandler defined, the other one is to catch the persistence exception and rethrow as application specific runtime exception and declare a generic page like "Technical Difficulties" in web.xml to handle this, the other one is to catch and rethrow as application specific checked exception and handle appropriately at the controller layer and show the user an interpreted message (this i dont like as the whole calling method stack should have the throws declared).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Exception Messages with Spring framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217800/custom-exception-messages-with-spring-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example I use to convert PersistentExceptions to a friendlier message. It is a method that goes in the Controller. Will this work for you?

```
/**
 * Shows a friendly message instead of the exception stack trace.
 * @param pe exception.
 * @return the exception message.
 */
@ExceptionHandler(PersistenceException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handlePersistenceException(final PersistenceException pe) {
    String returnMessage;
    if (pe.getCause()
            instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
        ConstraintViolationException cve =
                (ConstraintViolationException) pe.getCause();
        ConstraintViolation<?> cv =
                cve.getConstraintViolations().iterator().next();
        returnMessage = cv.getMessage();
    } else {
        returnMessage = pe.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    if (pe instanceof EntityExistsException) {
        returnMessage = messages.getMessage("user.alreadyexists");
    }
    return returnMessage;
}
```